# Using DebuggerDisplayAttribute for property/field

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a class with a property of standard type. In debugger I would like to see this particular property in some specific format. I'm using attribute DebuggerDisplay on that particular property, but in debugger's Watch window I see it applied to entire class, but not to target property. What am I missing?

```
class Transaction : ITransaction
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("{DateAsDebugString}")]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get;set;
    }

    string DateAsDebugString
    {
        get
        {
            var res = Date.ToShortDateString();
            if (Date.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Parse("00:00"))
                res += " " + Date.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

How to apply property level debugger formatting/visualizing rules?

Comment: Can you try adding a test `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` at the class level just to see if it takes effect?  Something like `[DebuggerDisplay("Testing")]`.

Comment: I just did a quick test in the project I have open at the moment, and am getting the same results as you.  From what I'm reading on MSDN, this is the correct usage; I'm a little perplexed as to why it isn't working as we expect.

Comment: Yes, class level attribute overrides the field level. It displays "Testing" for each class instance, properties are still ignored

Comment: My result with the attribute applied at both the class and the property level is a little different.  I'm seeing the class level attribute being ignored completely, and the property level one displaying as if it were applied at the class level (the same as you have in your screenshot).  I'm very tempted to say that this is a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: So even this behaviour is inconsistent. I double checked - if class level attribute exists then its value is displayed, otherwise it displays the value from the very first field/property -level attribute inside the class

Comment: Ahh, I figured out why my test results are different than yours.  I applied the attribute to one of my entity classes from Entity Framework for the test.  The dynamic proxy creation EF uses cleared the attribute from the class, just leaving the one of the property.  That's one mystery solved, but unfortunately doesn't help you solve your problem.  When I use a "normal" class not involved in Entity Framework, I get the same results as you exactly.

Comment: Found a bug report https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4134

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2015, as documented [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4134).  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have ever been fixed.

The same code in Visual Studio 2013 produces the expected results.

Comment: Six years later, nothing changed, the same thing still happens with VS 2022